# Where should i set the environment variable for java in ubuntu？

Tags: java

when i wanta set the environment variable for java:
someone said "~/.bashrc" and someone else said "/etc/profile" or "~/.profile"

i wanta know what different from these files?

And why the commod is  "export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH" but "export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin"

Comment: You don't need any environment variable for Java in Ubuntu. I don't have any neither I had to set it up ever.

Comment: As for the second part, `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH` makes sure that you don't loose what's already in the `PATH` variable. The second form would be overwriting `PATH`.

Comment: @m0skit0 beacause you are using the packaged JDK/JRE. If you want to use a custom one from a tarball, like Oracle JDK 1.8, then you will have it.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Oracle JDK's have Ubuntu-compatible packages as well. Just saying.

Comment: _"If you want to use a custom one **from a tarball**"_

Comment: [see this](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2014/07/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux.html) might help.